# Twilio Authy Callback issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio, authy

I am not sure whether the success callback of Twilio Authy's `register_user()` is firing or not. In my code

```
var authyUsrId;
//global.authyUsrId;

app.post('/forTwilio', function(req, res){
    // send the received data to Twilio Authy
    authy.register_user('maverick@example.com', '8753565612', '91', function(err, res){
        //global.authyUsrId = 'world';
                 authyUsrId = 'world';  
    });
    //res.set("Content-Type","application/json");
        res.json({name: 'hello', msg: authyUsrId});
    //res.json({name: 'hello', msg: global.authyUsrId});
});
```

Although new user is being added successfully to Authy and the response status is 200.

I want to set the value of authyUsrId to something in the success callback of `register_user()` and use it in the JSON response that I am sending to the POST request.

But in the response I am getting only this

`{name: 'hello'}`

Is there any way to debug particularly the register_user() callback portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I see you've solved the issue in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190752/twilio-authy-callback-issue/40192976#40192976), however I just wanted to explain what was going on and why that was the solution for you.

In your original code:

```
app.post('/forTwilio', function(req, res){
    authy.register_user('maverick@example.com', '8753565612', '91', function(err, res){
        authyUsrId = 'world';  
    });
    res.json({name: 'hello', msg: authyUsrId});
});
```

You set the `authyUsrId` variable within your callback from the API request to Authy. You then try to use that `authyUsrId` in the call to respond with JSON. However, [`register_user`](https://github.com/evilpacket/node-authy#register-new-user) is an **asynchronous** call, so the code below it runs before the code that is run within the callback. In fact, the `reguster_user` function has to make an HTTP request, so the callback is only run once that request is completed.

If you added logging to your original code, like this:

```
app.post('/forTwilio', function(req, res){
    authy.register_user('maverick@example.com', '8753565612', '91', function(err, res){
        console.log("Received response from Authy");
        authyUsrId = 'world';  
    });
    console.log("Sending JSON response");
    res.json({name: 'hello', msg: authyUsrId});
});
```

You would see in your log:

```
Sending JSON response
Received response from Authy
```

Your fix was to respond to you original web request within the callback, when you have all the data you needed. And that's why it works. If I were updating your original code it would now look like:

```
app.post('/forTwilio', function(req, res){
    authy.register_user('maverick@example.com', '8753565612', '91', function(err, res){
        authyUsrId = 'world';  
        res.json({name: 'hello', msg: authyUsrId});
    });
});
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Sending the response directly from the success callback of `register_user()` works.

```
app.post('/forTwilio', function(req, res){

    // send the received data to Twilio Authy
    authy.register_user('jimmy@example.com', '9224753123', '91', function(err, res2){
        res.send(res2.user);
    });
});
```